# How to debug Magento 2 code when using command lines?

Tags: magento2, debug, command-line

Running a script in command line is something we frequently do in Magento 2. For example, when creating new module, we must run `setup:upgrade` command. We cannot see all the information we need to know.

I know many Magento developers choose PHPStorm as their favorite editor. How we can use PHPStorm to debug Magento 2 command lines?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I configured "[PHP Remote Debug](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+Web+Applications+with+Run+Debug+Configurations)" in PHPStorm and just add XDEBUG_CONFIG before script to start debugging.

like `XDEBUG_CONFIG=idekey=phpstorm bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: How to setup debug in local. I am running php 5.5.15 with xdebug 2.2.3 on windows 10 and xampp . Enable listening and setting in configuration but console debug run without any logs

Comment: Hope this documentation help you https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+CLI+scripts+with+PhpStorm

Comment: it works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

@KAndy’s answer put me on the right track, but I am developing locally using vagrant and had to do the following to get this to work<sup>1</sup>

### Configure Xdebug:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1

;remote_connect_back will fail because REMOTE_ADDR header won’t be set
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"

;remote_host is ignored when remote_connect_back is enabled & successful; fallback
;Set to your HOST MACHINE IP
xdebug.remote_host=xx.xx.xx.xx 

;provides valuable insight if you can’t connect. Remove when done.
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

Set the `remote_host` IP to the IP address *of the host* (for me, using the IP address from `ifconfig` on the guest machine did not work - used  IP address acquired from the network settings on the host machine as the `remote_host`).

### Configure PHP Storm

1. Set up a server under `Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> PHP -> Servers` if you have not done so already.  (See screenshot)
   [image: Example Server Settings on PHP Storm]
2. `Run -> Edit Configurations` and add a `PHP Remote Debug.`

   - Choose the server you created in #1
   - Set the IDE Key to PHPSTORM 
     [image: Configuration Settings]
3. (Optional) `Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug` Check "Break at first line in PHP Scripts" (this can help debug issues with your path mapping.)
4. `Run -> Debug Vagrant` (or whatever you named your configuration in Step 2)
5. Run the script you'd like to debug (`magento setup:upgrade` in my case)

<sup>1</sup>I'm using ubuntu/trusty64 for reference

Answer (score 1):

after xdebug 3.0 update

Instead of setting the XDEBUG_CONFIG environment variable to idekey=PHPSTORM, you must set XDEBUG_SESSION to PHPSTORM:

export XDEBUG_MODE=debug XDEBUG_SESSION=1